# How can I use PHP Mail() function within PHP-FPM? On Nginx?

Tags: email, nginx, php

I have searched everywhere for this and I *really* want to resolve this. In the past I just end up using an SMTP service like SendGrid for PHP and a mailing plugin like SwiftMailer. However I want to use PHP.

Basically my setup (I am new to server setup, and this is my personal setup following a [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-lemp-on-ubuntu-12.10))

```
Nginx
Rackspace Cloud
PHP 5.3 PHP-FPM
Ubuntu 11.04
```

My `phpinfo()` returns this about the Mail entries:

```
mail.log                     no value
mail.add_x_header            On
mail.force_extra_parameters  no value

sendmail_from   no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

SMTP        localhost
smtp_port   25
```

Can someone help me to as why `Mail()` will not work - my script is working on all other sites, it is a normal mail command. Do I need to setup logs or enable some PHP port on the server?

My Sample script

```
<?
    # FORMS VARS

    // $to = $customers_email;
    // $to = $customers_email;

    $to = $_GET["customerEmailFromForm"];

    $subject = "Thank you for contacting Real-Domain.com";
    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    Thanks, your message was sent and our team will be in touch shortly.
    <img src='http://cdn.com/emails/thank_you.jpg' />
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <real-email@real-domain.com>' . "\r\n";

    // SEND MAIL
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Checking phpinfo() is a great idea, you made me realize I forgot to restart the fpm service to correct the mistake I made in php.ini (After spending three days tooling around with sendmail configuration changes!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As there is no value for `sendmail_from` you need to set one in `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_from = "you@example.com"
```

Or in the headers when you call to `mail`:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: you@example.com');
```

The email address should follow RFC 2822 for example:

- `you@example.com`
- `You <you@example.com>`

Failing that, have you actually installed a working email system?

If not, you can install postfix with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install postfix`

See below for more information on configuring postfix for use with PHP in Ubuntu:

https://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail

Comment: Does this have to be a real address?

Comment: No, providing you don't want to be able to receive responses.

Comment: The email address in your example does not follow RFC2822, see updated answer for valid examples.

Comment: See updated answer for information on installing/configuring email.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install postfix` and `sudo apt-get install mail` has fixed this! Thank you so much. Repped

Answer (score 15):

If found that on a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx and PHP-FPM (no apache), neither postfix nor mailutils were installed.

I used:
`sudo apt-get install postfix`

(as in the recommended answer)

AND

`sudo apt-get install mailutils`

to get everything working on my server. Both were required. An entry in PHP.ini (as mentioned in the recommended answer) may also have helped, but without both of the other packages, it wouldn't have made a difference.

Comment: You're welcome. After I set this up, I discovered that mail from my server wasn't getting delivered to my primary email domain (although it was getting delivered to other domains). It turns out postfix will (by default) try to deliver mail locally. The fix for this was to remove the domain name from the

Comment: whoops! bumped the "Add Comment" button early there...

The fix was to remove the domain name from the 

`mydestination` 

parameters in this file:

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Comment: Thanks... will +1 message. Cheers

Comment: This one worked for me, I didn't have to do any configuration in php.ini though.

Comment: For me it has helped as well without php.ini configuration